# Modify my code- better ways to insert changing values

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, linear-regression

I have a code that build scatter plot and display the linear regression trend line and the R square.
I calculate the R square manually by calculte the slope, intercept and the  r_value as following:

```
#Try for Linear Regression Moddel- still couldn't display anything on any scatter plot.
x = merged_data['NDVI']
y = merged_data['nitrogen']

from scipy.stats import linregress

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = linregress(x, y)
print('slope:',slope)
print('intercept:',intercept)
print('R:',r_value)
print('R^2:',(r_value**2))  

## Create Figure (empty canvas)
fig = plt.figure()
##Add set of axes to figure
axes = fig.add_axes([1,1,1,1]) # left, bottom, width, height (range 0 to 1)

##plot
plt.scatter(x,y,alpha=0.5)
plt.title('NDVI vs Nitrogen 17/6/2019')
plt.xlabel('NDVI')
#here I insert the calculted value manually according to the print values
plt.figtext(1.8,1.6, "y=-7.269X+10.11")
plt.figtext(1.8,1.55, "R^2=-0.017")
plt.ylabel('Nitrogen')
plt.show()
```

I have many different databases which I want to check this for them and I don't want to manually change everytime the test in the plot, is ther any way I can tell python automatically take those values and put them in the right place?

Comment: Could you please post a minimal example? And remove the part of the question which is not important to us to find an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import linregress

# generate dataset 1
x1 = np.random.normal(0,1,1000)
epsilon1 = np.random.normal(0,1,1000)
y1 = x1 + epsilon1

# generate dataset 2
x2 = np.random.normal(0,1,1000)
epsilon2 = np.random.normal(0,1,1000)
y2 = -x2 + epsilon2

def give_me_scatter(x, y, title, xlabel, ylabel):

    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = linregress(x, y)
    print('slope:',slope)
    print('intercept:',intercept)
    print('R:',r_value)
    print('R^2:',(r_value**2))  

    ## Create Figure (empty canvas)
    fig = plt.figure()
    ##Add set of axes to figure
    axes = fig.add_axes([1,1,1,1]) # left, bottom, width, height (range 0 to 1)

    ##plot
    plt.scatter(x,y,alpha=0.5)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.xlabel(xlabel)
    #here I insert the calculted value manually according to the print values
    plt.figtext(1.0,1.95, "y={0:.3}X+{1:.3}".format(slope, intercept))
    plt.figtext(1.0,1.90, "R^2={0:.3}".format(r_value**2))
    plt.ylabel(ylabel)
    plt.show()
```

For dataset 1:

```
give_me_scatter(x1, y1, 'x1 vs y1 10/12/2019', 'x1', 'y1')

slope: 0.9505854192888193
intercept: -0.0499255665055585
R: 0.6949004149189184
R^2: 0.482886586654485
```

[image]

For dataset 2:

```
give_me_scatter(x2, y2, 'x2 vs y2 10/12/2019', 'x2', 'y2')

slope: -0.9288542869184935
intercept: -0.008475040216075778
R: -0.6781390024143394
R^2: 0.4598725065955155
```

[image]

Comment: It looks good but for some reason when I try to run it I get no results, U thoughe maybe it's because it suppose to be in different cells but it didn't help. lines after this give output but this one not

Comment: please edit your original post and paste the exact code which does not give results; please also try restarting your python environment - either Jupyter Notebook or any IDE (Pycharm/Spyder etc.) are retry the code